# How to show the figure in an interactive 3D plot using Plotly in Colab?

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory

I have developed a 3D plot that is updated with a slider in Jupyter Notebook. I am using the following code structure:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py

from ipywidgets import interactive, VBox
import ipywidgets as widgets

from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=objectives)

fig = go.FigureWidget(
                go.Scatter3d(
                    x=fdf[objectives[0]], 
                    y=fdf[objectives[1]], 
                    z=fdf[objectives[2]],
                    hovertemplate= objectives[0] + " = %{x}<br>" + objectives[1] + " = %{y}<br>" + objectives[2] + " = %{z}<extra></extra>", 
                    mode ='markers',
                    marker = {'color' : colors}
                    ))

freq_slider = interactive(update_color, 
                          obj1_w=(0, 0, 0), 
                          obj2_w=(0, 0, 0),
                          obj3_w=(0, 0, 0))

vb = widgets.VBox((fig, freq_slider))
vb.layout.align_items = 'center'
vb
```

In Jupyter Notebook, it works perfectly... The slider updates the 3D plot, but in Colab, `fig` does not appear because the `show()` function is needed.

The following picture illustrates the 3D plot using Vbox that appears in Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

In Colab, the `fig` does not appear, only if I use the `show()` function, but it does not update when I use the slider.

Does anyone know how to plot the `fig` in this case? If it is not possible, is there another way to achieve the same result in Colab?